# Fedora Failing to Launch Linux Kernel 6.7.X, must boot twice to select kernel

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, boot, nvidia, startup

I have a newly built desktop running Fedora 39. (I have been told it may be important to note it has an NVidia GPU). A few days ago, the following occurred:

- I installed a normal system update
- For unrelated reasons, I rebooted the computer.*
- The OS loaded and hung on a blank screen with a terminal underscore flickering on and off
- On reboot, I was presented with a choice of three kernels I could select, plus one titled "Rescue". These are 6.7.13, and two marked as 6.6.X. Only one of the 6.6.X ones booted successfully (including the rescue one) and I was able to use my computer. Others hit the terminal underscore.
- Since then, I have generally had to boot my computer, hit the terminal underscore, reboot, get the kernel selection, and choose the right kernel.

Today, I installed more updates, including 6.7.14 of the kernel. The same thing occurred, except now the good 6.6.X one is the *third* kernel choice on the drop-down, not the second. This suggests to me that I only have so long until that one gets lost too and I'm out of luck.

I have no idea what might have caused this, other than one person blaming NVidia somehow. Whatever the case, what are my options to avoid this strange boot issue?

*Said "unrelated reason" was strangely that X stopped working, so I was no longer able to use my X-based window manager. I have no idea what happened or if this is relevant, but on the kernels I can currently boot to this doesn't happen, *but* the Wayland window managers are not available to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% positive you're hitting this [well known issue](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-6-7-3-545-29-06-550-40-07-error-modpost-gpl-incompatible-module-nvidia-ko-uses-gpl-only-symbol-rcu-read-lock/280908).

Your NVIDIA modules have failed to be rebuilt after a kernel update. You need to patch them.

If you're using RPMFusion, something has failed. They have long pushed an update fixing this.

```
nvidia-kmod-545.29.06-3.fc39.src [91 KiB]   Changelog by Leigh Scott (2024-02-01):
    - fix build with gcc-14 ad kernel-6.7.3
```

In the future please ask your NVIDIA related questions here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Not from RPMFusion, as my GPU's drivers are not there. Thank you for the info - I will have to either patch it myself by hand if I can figure out how, or simply stick with this kernel version until NVidia pushes out their fix.

Regarding asking my NVidia-related questions elsewhere: Good idea and suggestion, but in this particular case I really didn't know if NVidia had anything to do with it, and frankly I'm quite surprised to see that it was! I based the mention and tag of NVidia on one person (not me) idly speculating and decided to include it just in case (good thinking, it seems).